# Do Ingres and Vectorwise Databases support functionality similar to TRUNCATE table in SQL Server? If so, what is the syntax?

Tags: sql, ingres, vectorwise

Trying to find if there is something similar to TRUNCATE TABLE in these 2 database systems.

Comment: You would have to check their documentation, but it seems like a very reasonable command to support for any database that supports SQL.

Answer (score 1):

```
MODIFY mytable TO TRUNCATED
```

is the equivalent SQL for Ingres/Vector/ActianX